# How to execute an Ant task only if a file is changed?

Tags: ant

I have been trying to use the following code to get the task working only if the file is changed but it doesn't seem to work. The task is called irrespective of whether there is a change or not.

```
<target name ="widget-change" depends="configuration-for-widgets">
    <fileset dir="${src-location}">         
        <include name="com.myApp.MainClasses.myClassOne.java"/>
        <include name="com.myApp.MainClasses.myClassTwo.java"/>
        <modified update="true"/>
    </fileset>          
    <antcall target="gwt-compile"/>         
</target>
```

Comment: I assume that your `gwt-compile` target is conditional on `compile.set`.

Comment: @sudocode Yes, that's the plan.

Comment: I had to remove the compile.set as it is not supported by the modified tag!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an ant version less that 1.8.0?

In [Getting the Ant  selector to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796124/127035), the asker resolved by using a `depend` selector instead of modified.

In [Ant bug 32958](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=32597), an workaround suggested is to use a nested update `param`:

> You may be able to work around this by using a nested
>
> ```
>       <param name="update" value="false"/>
> ```
>
> instead of the update attribute.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, your answer helped me a lot. I have now modified the code and added param to it. However, I see that when I comment the <filename> tags and include <copy> tag only then the <modified> works fine! This getting a little weird now. :( What I want to achieve is that the compiler should run only when the files are changed. I want to cache the files and run the compiler when they are changed.